# How to define c# controller using action-xhr of Amp-form

Tags: c#, amp-form

How can I write a `c#` controller for amp form `action-xhr` in below code?

```
<form method="post" class="subscription-form" action-xhr="/Home/Subscribe"
        custom-validation-reporting="show-all-on-submit" target="_top" on="submit-error:submit-error.show">
```